# Broken oh my zshell in IntelliJ Idea on Ubuntu

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, zsh

I have troubles with Oh my zshell in IntelliJ Idea running on Ubuntu. When I run docker-compose, after a short while the lines turn to look like this:

┼▒├⎽-⎽├⎼␊▒└␋┼±_1   ≠ [1] 2018/05/14 14:16:56.617909 [TRC] 127.0.0.1:47348 - ␌␋␍:2 - <<- [MSG *STAN.▒␌┐.6├Z0␌R▒UP7Q1DO┌␍┤BLXW6.├␊└⎻.├01.├␊└⎻␊⎼▒├┤⎼␊.6├Z0␌R▒UP7Q1DO┌␍┤BLX␤┼ 11 24]
^CG⎼▒␌␊°┤┌┌≤ ⎽├⎺⎻⎻␋┼±... (⎻⎼␊⎽⎽ C├⎼┌+C ▒±▒␋┼ ├⎺ °⎺⎼␌␊)
S├⎺⎻⎻␋┼± ␤␋⎽├⎺⎼≤*┼▒⎼⎼▒├┤⎽_1        ... ␍⎺┼␊

Any idea how to fix? 
After upgrade of IntelliJ from 2017.3 to 2018.1 the problem remains. Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Are you using a powerline or other theming scheme for zsh that require patched fonts such as nerdfonts or powerline-fonts with special glyphs? If so, then in Intellij's terminal settings the font needs to be set correctly to one of those type of fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Asuggestion would be to check your LANG and LOCALE environment variables both on host and guest.

Color on your shell settings can also produce garbage when run in an IDE.